# Geneate Custom log Log4j.xml

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j

I have simple program in java & want to generate the custom log using log4j.xml

I am getting the below output with the mentioned code at bottom.

```
2017-01-30 23:23:03 DEBUG Log4jXmlConfigurationExample:13 - Log4j appender configuration is successful !!
2017-01-30 23:23:03 INFO  Log4jXmlConfigurationExample:15 - Info message ---------- >
2017-01-30 23:23:03 ERROR Log4jXmlConfigurationExample:17 - Error message ------>
```

Here I getting 4 column like "DateTime"   "LogType"   "JavafileName"   "Message"

Now I want the fifth column as userId. So I am expecting that output file will have 5 column as "DateTime"   "LogType"   "JavafileName"   "Message"   "Counter"

Could someone help here how can I make the custom changes in log4j.xml

Yes ofcourse counter will be dynamically generated and will get in simple java program

log4.xml

```
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="false" />
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <param name="file" value="C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/Logs/my_logs.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern"
        value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</root>
```

Java Code

```
public static int counter =1;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j-config.xml");
    counter++; 
    logger.debug("Log4j appender configuration is successful !!");
    counter++;      
    logger.info("Info message ---------- >");       
    counter++;
    logger.error("Error message ------>");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables used (e.g. %d) are listed in the conversion pattern: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html
I don't see a userID

Comment: No I am not saying I want to print UserID as a default paramater..I just wanted to print one paramater which would be dynamically generated in java program. take a example of counter I have updated the question with counter code.

Comment: Then output the value as logger.debug("value of counter = " + counter);

Comment: But I want it as a seperate Column in generted log file. Not with combination of message.

Comment: You only have the variables listed by log4j. Unless you want to rewrite it, you have to use what they give you.

Comment: Can we not use kind of custom appender?? if you have any idea

Comment: I'm sure you could change the appender class you're using. Then place it in your classpath before log4j. But again, it's rewriting a log4j component.

Comment: any link or example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078561/how-to-specify-custom-extended-logger-in-log4j-xml-file?rq=1

Comment: Was this helpful?